# looking for a bootstrap modal plugin to handle iFrames

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am looking to include a page of ours without having to use Ajax, for now iFrames are the best option. However on the page we have 10+ links that could point to a modal.

Is there a way we can get a Modal to load an iframe by using the standard format?

```
<a href="'.$url.'/popupviewresponse/'.$responses->response_id.'/'.seoUrl($responses->title).'" data-toggle="modal">Modal-link</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer, we chose to use a plugin https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-bootstrap-scripting/pull/69